# Media screen não funciona com boostrap 4

Tags: css, media-queries

```html
<?php
session_start(); // Inicia a sessão
include_once("func/functions.php"); // Chama o arquivo de funções padrão.
include_once("func/f_exames.php"); // Chama o arquivo de funções específicas.
if ($_SESSION['userPermission'] <> 14) // Valida o grau de permissão para mostrar botão de navegação entre motoristas
   $show="hidden";
   
if (is_null($_SESSION['userName'])) // Valida se existe usuário logado
 header('location:./index.php');
 
$codMot = $_SESSION['userCodMot'];
$foto = (isset($_SESSION['userPhoto'])) ? 'fotos/'.$_SESSION['userPhoto'] : 'fotos/YAPONYRA_FOTO.jpg';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title> Exames e Cursos </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript"  src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"  src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"  src="js/comandos.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/exames.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/padrao.css">
 </head>
 <body onmousemove="acao();"> <!-- Função acao() faz verificação de ociosidade no painel, após determinado tempo ele fecha. -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.hitransportes.com.br/" target="_blank">HItransportes | </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"id="collapsibleNavbar">
     <ul class="navbar-nav">
       <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="inicio.php"><img src="logo/geral.png" /> Inicio </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item <?php echo $show; ?>">
           <a class="nav-link" href="requisicao.php"><img src="logo/abastecimento.png" /> Abastecimento </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="dashboard.php"><img src="logo/relatorio.png" /> Relatórios </a>
       </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="perfil.php"><img src="logo/perfil.png" /> Perfil</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><img src="logo/outros.png" /> Outros</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="exames.php"><img src="logo/exames.png" /> Exames/Cursos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="func/f_parametros.php?func=sair"><img src="logo/sair.png" /> Sair</a>
          </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </nav>
   <div class="row topo ">
    <div class="col-sm-1 user-foto"><img src="<?php echo $foto ?> "></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 user-info" style="text-align:left"><label><?php echo $_SESSION['userName']; ?> </label></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 user-info" style="text-align:center"><label>Nome do Sistema</label></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
     <div class="head-docs">
      <h4>Documentos</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="documentos">
      <div class="ex-title">Tipo Documento</div>
      <div class="ex-title">Data Vencto.</div>
      <div class="ex-title">Expira em</div>
      <?php echo cnh($codMot)?>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
     <div class="head-title">
      <h4>Exames</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="grid">
      <div class="ex-title">Lançamento</div>
      <div class="ex-title">Cód.Motorista</div>
      <div class="ex-title">Motorista</div>
      <div class="ex-title">Cód.Curso</div>
      <div class="ex-title">Exames</div>
      <div class="ex-title">OBS</div>
      <div class="ex-title">Vencto.Curso</div>
      <div class="ex-title">Expira em</div>
      <?php echo exames($codMot) ?>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
     <div class="head-title">
      <h4>Direção Defensiva</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="grid">
     <div class="ex-title">Lançamento</div>
      <div class="ex-title">Cód.Motorista</div>
      <div class="ex-title">Motorista</div>
      <div class="ex-title">Cód.Curso</div>
      <div class="ex-title">Cursos</div>
      <div class="ex-title">OBS</div>
      <div class="ex-title">Vencto.Curso</div>
      <div class="ex-title">Expira em</div>
      <?php echo dirDef($codMot) ?>
     </div> 
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
     <div class="head-title">
      <h4>Treinamentos</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="treinamento">
     <div class="grid">
      <div class="ex-title">Lançamento</div>
      <div class="ex-title">Cód.Motorista</div>
      <div class="ex-title">Motorista</div>
      <div class="ex-title">Cód.Curso</div>
      <div class="ex-title">Cursos</div>
      <div class="ex-title">OBS</div>
      <div class="ex-title">Vencto.Curso</div>
      <div class="ex-title">Expira em</div>
      <?php echo treinamento($codMot) ?>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
     <div class="head-title">
      <h4>Mopp</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="mop">
      <div class="grid">
       <div class="ex-title">Lançamento</div>
       <div class="ex-title">Cód.Motorista</div>
       <div class="ex-title">Motorista</div>
       <div class="ex-title">Cód.Curso</div>
       <div class="ex-title">Cursos</div>
       <div class="ex-title">OBS</div>
       <div class="ex-title">Vencto.Curso</div>
       <div class="ex-title">Expira em</div>
       <?php echo mop($codMot) ?>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="leg1">
       
   </div>
   <div class="text-leg1">
    Vencimento a partir de  90 dias
   </div>
   <div class="leg2">   
   </div>
   <div class="text-leg2">
    Vencimento a partir de 60 dias
   </div>
   <div class="leg3">   
   </div>
   <div class="text-leg3">
    Vencimento a partir de 30 dias
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

No meu projeto, quero alterar alguns tamanhos e espaçamentos no menu, estou usando o Bootstrap4,  e outro arquivo CSS,nesse arquivo, mudei algumas coisas e deu certo, porém,quando fui adicionar uma @media screen, simplesmente não pega,não funciona....
Alguém sabe me dizer o por que ?
OBS: Só o @media que não funciona, o resto ta tudo belza.

---

```
body
{
  color: #000;
}
.topo
{
    margin-top: 1%;
}
nav li
{
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right:5px;
}
div .list-group a
{
  color: #000;
}
.user-foto
{
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    width: 70px;
}
.user-foto img
{
    width: 72px;
    height:72px;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
.user-info
{
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-top: 1%;
}
.user-info label
{
    font-size: 140%;
}
.card
{
    margin-top: 1%;
}
@media only screen and(min-width: 880px) and(max-width: 1204px){

    nav li
    {
        padding-left: 1px;
        padding-right:1px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Acredito que você está implementando ela da maneira errada. [Confere aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) o manual de media query no W3school.

Comment: Tiagão só com o CSS não da para te responder direito, coloca o HTML também, inclusive com a `<head>`. Mas o que posso te falar é que seu @media está fora do padrão oficial de medidas do Bootstrap. De qq forma vc tb pode tentar colocando `!important ` nos estilos...